"How can I disable specific dates in a date input field?"
I can´t disable specifics dates in a input date.
I'm currently developing a Hotel Booking website, and I want to disable specific dates in a date input field. When I make a reservation for a room, that room is reserved for other dates as well. Therefore, I need to disable specific dates. How can I do that?.
<input (input)="ponerPrecio()" [min]="fechaMinima" [(ngModel)]="fechaSalida" #fechaFinalInput id="fechaFin" name="fechaFinal" type="date" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full ps-10 p-2.5" placeholder="Fecha de salida">


I guess that when a room is booked you can set the period that is taken. Make a query that returns which dates the room is booked, after that filter it in the back or send the dates that is taken to the front-end. Without any more code I can only guess. Please add more details to the question.

You can not get it using a simple input type="date" (see the docs. Use any of the well-know Angular libraries: mat-angular, ng-bootstrap, nebula...
